# iOS MapKit - drawing shapes on map

Tags: ios, mapkit

I'd like to allow users to mark some area on map. This area should be any closed shape. For instance user can draw something like this:

[image]

In next step I'd like to calculate region of this shape. How can I achive this?

Comment: What do you mean by "calculate region"? Are you trying to calculate the area? Turn the shape into a MKCoordinateRegion? Something else?

Comment: Sorry that I was not clear. I'd like to calculate the area of drawn shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MKPolygon`.

First of all you'll need to disable user interaction on the map view so that it won't move around while you're trying to draw on it. Next up you can use the `UIResponder` functions `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved` and `touchesEnded`. As you move through these three functions you can record the points the user has pressed. Lastly you can then create an MKPolygon from this array of points that you have recorded.